# How to use app.listen(port, host) with public hostname?

Tags: node.js, express, host

Can I put public domain name as host argument in app.listen(port, host)?

I know my ip, and I have 3 domain names on this ip. domain1.com, domain2.com all on same ip. Now, I'm using switch in app.get('/') to routing request of different domain names. However, I'm wondering is there a way to route host when setting up app.listen.

I found the entry of app.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback]) is really vague on expressjs website. There's nothing about the "host" argument. I know it can be set to localhost or 127.0.0.1. But my code failed when I put public domain name in it.
Can anybody explain how the host argument works in app.listen? Thank you.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {res.send("hello")});
app.listen(3000, "my.domain");
```

Error code:

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available myip:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1281:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1346:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1485:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:65:10)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1325:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: 'myip',
  port: 3000
}
```

The server can't run.

Comment: The server will only listen on ip addresses which are local to the box you are running it on.  by default it wil listen on 0.0.0.0 or all available hosts... you can only set it to an ip that is on a network interface, no the system which you are running the server. if you have multiple domains pointing to the same ip you will need to use different ports... you would use something like nginx to route to the domains.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start server with hostname `0.0.0.0` and get access from other network points by your IP (check by [`ifconfig`](https://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-command-examples/)).

Comment: Sorry. I don't get what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the public ip of your public domain, then put it in the app.listen.
Example if your public ip is 1.2.3.4:
`app.listen(3000,'1.2.3.4');`